# Using multiple sidebars in CKEditor's 5 Comments plugin

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am implementing a multiroot baloon editor that includes the Comments plugin.

So I have something like this:

```js
class MultirootBaloonEditor extends Editor {}
```

In other files I import my custom class and I initialize multiple editors.
Inside the configuration, however, I get to specify only one sidebar like this:

```js
MultirootBaloonEditor.create(
  {
    // HTML elements created:
    header: document.querySelector('#myHeader'),
    main: document.querySelector('#myMain'),
    footer: document.querySelector('#myFooter'),
  },
  {
    initialData: someInitialData,
    // CommentsAdapter deals with the data store for Comments:
    extraPlugins: [CommentsAdapter],  
    // HERE, only ONE sidebar can be specified??!?: 
    sidebar: {
      container: document.querySelector('#sidebar'),
    }
  }
)
```

Is it possible to use different sidebars, each attached to their respective editor in the case of a multi-root baloon instances?
From the code above it seems only one sidebar can be used.